# Docker: copy folder into multiple images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For example, I have the next structure of project:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── library
└── _services
    └──_service1
    |  └── Dockerfile
    ├──_service2
    |  └── Dockerfile
    └──_service3
       └── Dockerfile
```

How can I copy `library` into each service? Or is it exist a better way to create services images with `library` package?

Comment: So if I understand correctly , you need the same service spawned multiple times with different configurations in library? Could you please elaborate! Because the solution varies on what exactly you need

Comment: @chaosguru
No, there are different services, but all of them have a duplicated code. I moved this duplication to `library` and want to share this library over my services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy files that are in a parent directory of where you Dockerfile is.

Of course you don't want to copy your library content into each service directory but you can.

1. Create a distinct Dockerfile for each service at the top level.
   Eg:

   docker-compose.yml
   library
   Dockerfile.service1
   Dockerfile.service2
   Dockerfile.service3

then each dockerfile can `COPY` the library in.

2. If your library is a fundamental part of your services, you can simply create an image for it and make it the base image for your services.

Eg:
    base
      library
      Dockerfile
    services
      Dockerfile.service1
      Dockerfile.service2
      Dockerfile.service3

with Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY library/...
```

docker build -t base .

and a Dockerfile.serviceN

```
  FROM base
```

Generally, I find it better to not include building of Dockerfile in the docker compose. You build your services when needed, push them to an image repository (eg: quay.io, docker.io) and your docker compose file pulls them in at deploy time.

Comment: `library` contains ~50 LOC, so it doesn't make sense to me to utilize 2nd option.
I've done like you suggested:

`docker-compose.yml library Dockerfile.service1 Dockerfile.service2 Dockerfile.service3`

It is not looking fine but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way of maintaining is single image and having Docker Volumes  .  You can also specify the volume in `docker-compose.yml` and use the shared data.

Volumes in compose : `https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes`.
Volumes in Docker  :  `https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use volumes to share code: it means the images won't be self-contained.